# I'm using Blazor with TailwindCSS. Can I make tailwindcss scan components that are in a RCL?

Tags: blazor, tailwind-css, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

Currently, I have my `tailwind.config.js` set up to scan for files that contain tailwind class names.

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  content: ["**/*.razor", "**/*.cshtml", "**/*.html", "**/*.razor.css"],
  theme: {},
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

I am trying to reference the components in my RCL which also contain tailwind classes so I can generate one CSS file.

I have already tried to work with two CSS files and configs. One for the Blazor project and the other for the RCL. But as a results, I get both the CSS files overriding each other on certain components.

But since RCLs get compiled into DLLs I have no clue where to start to reference the RCL components for tailwindcss to scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the path to your Razor Class Library (RCL) in Tailwind content directly, if you haven't done it already

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: "jit",
  content: [
    "**/*.razor",
    "**/*.cshtml",
    "**/*.html",
    "**/*.razor.css",
    "PATH/TO/RCL/components/**/*"
  ],
  theme: {},
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Would this work with a relative path?